# $A \subset R^n$ , that A open and volume and $f : A \to R$ a continuous no negative function that $f(x_0) > 0$ for some $x_0$. Prove $\int_{A} f > 0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What I thought is using the theorem that prove an integrable and no negative function that $\int_{A} f = 0$ then the set {$x \in A$ : $f(x) \neq 0$} has measure zero. Apart from that I know that I can apply this theorem because a continuous function is integrable.

Comment: Hint: Since $f(x_0)> 0$, can you find $B(x_0,r)$ such that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in B(x_0,r)$ and $B(x_0, r) \subset A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x_0)>0$ and, and $x_0=(x_0^1,\ldots,x_0^n)\in A$, with $A$ open, since $f$ is continuous, there exists a $\delta>0$, such that
$$
B_\delta(x_0)=\{x\in\mathbb R^n: |x-x_0|<\delta\}\subset A,
$$
and
$$
|x-x_0|<\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{f(x_0)}{2}
$$
and hence
$$
|x-x_0|<\delta\quad\Longrightarrow\quad f(x)>\frac{f(x_0)}{2}.
$$
Now, since $f(x)\ge 0$ ,for all $x\in A$, then
$$
\int_A f\ge \int_{B_\delta(x_0)} f \ge \int_{B_\delta(x_0)} \frac{f(x_0)}{2} =
\frac{f(x_0)}{2}\cdot \mathrm{vol}\big(B_\delta(x_0)\big)>0.
$$

Comment: Thank you I did not find out that. :)